# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3y^2+x}{4y^2+5}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y=f(x)$ be the solution of the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3y^2+x}{4y^2+5}$$
I would like to find $y=f(x)$.

**Original question**:[image]

**My attempt**: I tried to apply the general methods to solve the linear differential equation but couldn't get the desired solution.

Comment: You don't need to find the solution of the initial value problem to answer the multiple choice question.

Comment: @TravisWillse to be fair, this is not really multiple choice, this is a select all that apply question

Comment: @NinadMunshi You're right---but the same comment still applies. In fact, I'd be surprised if this particular i.v.p. had a solution in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that if $x \geq \frac{15}{4}$

$$y' = \frac{3y^2+x}{4y^2+5} \geq \frac{3y^2+\frac{15}{4}}{4y^2+5} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Which means at the very least

$$f(x) \geq \frac{3}{4}x-\frac{45}{16} \implies \int_{\frac{15}{4}}^{\frac{27}{4}} f(x)\:dx \geq \int_{\frac{15}{4}}^{\frac{27}{4}}\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{45}{16}\:dx = \frac{27}{8}$$

so options $1$ and $2$ are in but option $3$ is out. Can you continue with option $4$?

Comment: Thank you so much,

 I had been trying to solve this differential equation.

Just realized that I was wrong.